# insert row into top of table

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to add a record to the top of a MySQL database during "INSERT" statement? Like, the latest entry will be shown first?

:D thanks!

Comment: a mysql table has no default order, it all depends on how you select from the table

Comment: like the table will already be in order from latest, and will no longer need ORDER BY during the viewing of the database records. :) thanks again!!

Comment: Is it possible to insert a new row at top of MySQL table?

Here you can find the solution (for example using as primarey key the date of insert), with this always is you do correctly the select you always will found as first position the last insert.

Comment: of course i've also seen that thread. it's just that all that did was arrange the table per row **after** the entry was saved. i was wondering if it was possible to insert a row to the very top permanently. :) still saying "thanks".

Comment: There is no such thing as the "*top of the table*" in a relational database.

Comment: Where did you get this crazy idea of "top of the table"? It looks like you totally don't understand what a relational database is. You should probably use files instead of the database. Databases are invented, among other things, in order to fetch the data the way you like. You shouldn't worry how you *insert* the data, you just need to worry how you *get it out*. If you worry about top, bottom, or middle of the table - you're using a nuclear bomb to kill a fly. Just don't.

Comment: @N.B. Where did you get this crazy idea that `putting a row on top of the table` is a crazy idea ? It should be so normal thing. Crazy is the fact that it's not possible.

Comment: @bonaca - once you learn that there is no order, you can understand that there doesn't exist such a thing like "top of the table". The whole notion is that there's no order, you **choose** the order while you **retrieve** the data. It's all explained in previous comments and my comment. It becomes much, much easier to get this whole thing once you *learn* this superbly simple system. Then you stop wondering about what's crazy and what isn't, all that's left is hard facts and truth.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible.

I think your use case is about retrieving data in a certain order - which is the purpose of query rather than DML.

There is a dirty workaround...

- Create a new table
- Insert the "late" record to the new table
- Insert existing records to the new table
- Drop old table
- Rename new table to old table

Comment: :) thanks. shuld've read this first, i guess.